# Image Texture Mapping, texture is stretched along the z-axis

Tags: texturing

I'm wondering what I'm missing to make this texture applied onto the back walls as if z-axis scale has gone off the scale, rather than rendering as tiles displayed by the material preview.

Thanks much[image]

Comment: You may want window mapping (from your texture coordinate node), or you may want a project-from-view UV map.  In either case, you'll want an orthogonal view (numpad 5.)

Comment: It's a problem of UV mapping. Your wall is probably not UV unwrapped yet but you use UV coordinates output from your textures coordinate node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wall is **not UV unwrapped** yet. To use the `UV` output from the Texture Coordinates node, you need to UV unwrap your mesh first, otherwise you will always end up with undesired results like this.

You can fix this by either :

-By selecting your wall in Edit mode and press `U`, then `Unwrap` and playing around with the `Scale` and `Location` of your Mapping node or

-By using the `Generated` output of the Texture coordinates node and playing around with the `Scale` and `Location` of your Mapping node.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain and provide options for the fix @mqbaka!!! Very helpful and worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad I helped. You may accept the answer so that the topic will be considered as solved?